# Bluetooth antenna problem with SIM800C on my board

Tags: antenna, bluetooth, gsm, pcb-antenna

I have designed a board with a SIM800C and I have followed all details with its given datasheet. Everything is working well except the Bluetooth that gives very low antenna strength (less than 10cm.)

https://simcom.ee/documents/SIM800C-DS/SIM800C-DS_Hardware_Design_V1.01.pdf

Things that I have tried:

1. Three different modules.
2. One SIM800C wired on the air to see if some signal collision is happening on my board
3. Connecting and trying 3 different WiFi 2.4Ghz, 50ohm antennas directly to the BT pin of the SIM800C.
4. Adding almost random capacitors and a few random resistors between/on antenna and BT pin.
5. Have tried other BT module's antenna by directly wiring it to the SIM800C BT pin and disconnecting its path from original module.

None of these even helped to increase to 50cm of BT antenna strength. I do not understand it at all. What I am missing? Do I need to add a specific resistor or capacitor to make it work? In the datasheet it says it is usually zero without any capacitors.

I am not an expert with antenna stuff and could somebody tell me step by step what do I need to do? I really need help, please! note that GND is connected to GSM by default in the module and works fine. I have 4.1v-3A on my module.

I attach some pictures, although if needed I can share more.

[image: Try with one other BT module antenna! Its connection is disconnected at module]

[image: Try on-air with antenna!]

[image]

Comment: It looks like you’re trying to connect the BT antenna using ordinary hookup wire. You need a 50 ohm RF feedline, either PCB micro strip or miniature coax cable. You also need to understand the requirements for the antenna you choose — many only work with a proper ground plane. Can you show full schematic and PCB layout?

Comment: Thanks for the attention. I already have tried 50 ohm RF wire and antenna too. I added a new picture (3rd) and the antenna with black wire is the one. But as you can see (Second image) I have tried IC on-air and the Sim800c's BT antenna pin is connected directly to the antenna! So I feel now it should not be related to the schematic anymore, isn't it?